# How to connect django with mysql database proberly

Tags: python, mysql, django

### First of all im tring to connect a django_project to mysql by editting my_project/settings.py file with the code below

I created a database called (**mydatabase**) and user with full privileges called (***admin***) identified by (***admin***), then i tried to connect my django project with **mydatabase** by the following code below:

> django_project\mysettings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': 'admin',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

Everything was working as expected until i changed that **DATABASES** dictionary from the default value in file above and it resulted by the following error when i tried to run the server with `py manage.py runserver`

### Watching for file changes with StatReloader

### performing system checks...

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', system error: 0")
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', system error: 0")
```

I didn't provide the traceback for the error as it seemed unneccessary, **I would provide it if needed**

---

I have both mysql client and mysql connector modules installed :

```
mysql-connector-python 8.0.19
mysqlclient            1.4.6
```

Comment: Are you sure your this is  mysql and is on port 5432?

Comment: set HOST to localhost and port 3306 if your database is on local

Comment: @iklinac Oh, it isn't, actually it's 3306 and it worked when i changed it ty, I thought  while using django for devolpment purposes i must use the 5432 port but it works fine now after changing it to 3306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Port 3306 is the default port for the MySQL Protocol, which is used by the mysql client
>   You are using 5432 which is default for Postgresql.